# bower'ing in multiple items (velocity.js)

Tags: javascript, bower

I am trying to bower in multiple scripts (if i can), specifically velocity.js's ui kit.

The current bower file has this  -

```
   "main": "./velocity.js",
```

And I'm wondering if I can drop in multiple scripts in here somehow (i'm very new to this). something like

```
 "second" : "./velocity.ui.js",
```

I a not sure how exactly this works, but I just want it drop drop that script in the index/html right under the first one. Is this possible?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the correct way to do this is to provide an array to the `main` section.

```
"main": [
    "./velocity.js",
    "./velocity.ui.js"
 ]
```

That is to define `main` scripts for build systems like `grunt` and `gulp`. How are you copying your files from `bower_components` to your app folder? Or are you just referencing them from `bower_components`?